# Why the compiled binary gets smaller when -gencode used?

Tags: cuda, nvcc

Why the compiled binary gets smaller when -gencode used?

My GPU's capability is 3.0.

NVCC option:

Without `-gencode` option：

1,780,520 bytes

`-gencode=arch=compute_30,code=sm_30`:

1,719,080 bytes, gets smaller

`-gencode=arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61`:

1,780,800 bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nvidia [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#shorthand-3) tells that:

Example:

```
nvcc x.cu
```

is equivalent to:

```
nvcc x.cu --gpu-architecture=compute_30 --gpu-code=sm_30,compute_30
```

but in your case:

```
nvcc x.cu -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=sm_30
```

is equivalent to:

```
nvcc x.cu --gpu-architecture=compute_30 --gpu-code=sm_30
```

which does not include the PTX code for the virtual architecture (such as compute_30)