# NVCC -arch -code

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, nvcc

I'm confused with the NVCC documentation: [3.2.7. Options for Steering GPU Code Generation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-steering-gpu-code-generation)

What's the difference between

`nvcc -arch=compute_50 -code=sm_50,compute_50` (equivalent to `nvcc -arch=sm_50`)

and

`nvcc -arch=compute_50 -code=sm_50`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
nvcc -arch=compute_50 -code=sm_50,compute_50 (equivalent to nvcc -arch=sm_50)
```

embeds both PTX and SASS into your fatbinary.  The inclusion of PTX into your fatbinary makes it more likely that your code will run on future/higher than cc 5.0 architectures.

This:

```
nvcc -arch=compute_50 -code=sm_50
```

embeds only SASS.  The code will run only on an architecture that is binary compatible with cc5.0

More info is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599189/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-multiple-arch-flags-in-nvidias-nvcc-compiler/17599585#17599585) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35656294/cuda-how-to-use-arch-and-code-and-sm-vs-compute/35657430#35657430).

Comment: I see that this was already explained to you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47532255/why-the-compiled-binary-gets-smaller-when-gencode-used)

Comment: Thanks for explanation and links. I also find this part [5.4. Virtual Architectures](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#virtual-architectures) which is very clear. Sorry for the last uncompleted comment.

Comment: BTW, what does SASS stand for?

Comment: SASS is the assembly code (machine code) used by NVIDIA GPUs.  It is documented [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#instruction-set-ref).  If you're asking for how was the SASS acronym created, NVIDIA doesn't give a clear public definition that I know of.  I have seen "streaming assembly" and also "shader assembly", as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798258/what-is-sass-short-for)